# eclipse jdt syntax highlighting of constants

Tags: java, eclipse, constants, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-jdt

Anyone know of a simple way of adding syntax highlighting rules to the default syntax coloring in the eclipse java jdt? I would like to show constants of various kinds in a specific colour.

Such as: final members and enum value literals (not the enum type name).
Numbers and strings are already supported, as is static final member.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences -> JAVA -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring

And in Element box select ***static final fields*** under java you can change your color by what you want for your constant

Comment: Yep, thanks. Numbers, strings, and static final are supported, but non static final is not, nor enum value literals. Good that I can get some the way I prefer, but it would be great to have a way to get the rest as well. I'm trying to find a way to deal with the rest of the "constant"-ish variants.